# I can't use xsl:key function on XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My fragment which doesn't work:

```
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="//LineItems/LineItem" use="EVENT_DATE" />
    
        <xsl:for-each select="//LineItems/LineItem">
    

            <tr class="standardText">
                <td s-cel="" s-crt="EVENT_DATE">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(EVENT_DATE, 'dd/MM/yyyy')"/>
                </td>
// ...
```

Error:

...has invalid child element 'key' in namespace...

[image]

Why? Other XSLT 1.0 functions work...

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not fragments taken out of context.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The problem was already solved, it was trivial as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:key` is a top-level element only to be used as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`. Your error message suggests you have tried to put it into an `xsl:template`, move it outside of any `xsl:template`.

Comment: Thank you, I can't see an error now... I guess I will need to correct the path in the "match" to full one starting from root...

Comment: A pattern, whether used for the `xsl:key` or the `xsl:template` element, doesn't have to start from the root, `match="LineItems/LineItem"` will match any `LineItem` elements having a `LineItems` parent, whether it is used in a key declaration or a template declaration.